# React Enzyme testing Portals

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I've been trying to find a solution for testing this fairly straight forward Portal with not much luck. Mounting seems to be the solution I can with Enzyme which I'm using for unit tests, but none of the solutions I have found seem to work for me? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**PORTAL**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import UGCGalleryOverlay from './UGCGalleryOverlay';

const rootElem = document.getElementById('ugc-gallery-overlay');

class UGCGalleryOverlayPortal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    rootElem.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    rootElem.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    const { onClick, products, source, mainImage } = this.props;

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <UGCGalleryOverlay
        onClick={onClick}
        products={products}
        source={source}
        mainImage={mainImage}
      />
    , rootElem)
    }
};

UGCGalleryOverlayPortal.displayName = 'UGCGalleryOverlayPortal';

UGCGalleryOverlayPortal.propTypes = {
  products: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
  mainImage: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  source: PropTypes.shape({
    user: PropTypes.shape({
      displayName: PropTypes.string,
      image: PropTypes.shape({
        smallSquare: PropTypes.shape({
          link: PropTypes.string,
        }),
      }),
    }),
  }).isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default UGCGalleryOverlayPortal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found a solution already.  But, for people looking for answers in the future ...

It looks like you are passing the wrong element to `ReactDom.createPortal()`.
You are passing the `rootElem` to the portal, but you should pass the element created in the `constructor`.

```js
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
          <UGCGalleryOverlay
            onClick={onClick}
            products={products}
            source={source}
            mainImage={mainImage}
          />
        , this.el)
```

`createPortal()` will render the children/components into the div you created (instead of creating a new div) that `div` is then appended to a root Element.

see, [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)